# Symfony2: How to protect uploaded media?

Tags: file, symfony, symfony-2.5

I have uploaded files located at /web/uploads and I need give access only to specific users. My users are not in security context (I know that is bad solution).
I think I must move files away from /web folder (like /uploads) and create controller which will process access to files. Am I right or exist better solution?

Symfony version is 2.5.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is solid. In the controller action, you can setup your logical calls to validate file access.

I would recommend creating a Service for this, so that you can reuse it outside of that specific controller if ever needed.

You can read a bit more on http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

At it's core, Symfony supports and pushes towards a service oriented architecture, controllers exist mostly to facilitate the handling of Request and Response objects.

Comment: and save your files in the DB as BLOB: 1. you need not to generate unique filenames 2. no accidentally overwriting possible 3. deployments stay cleaner

Comment: From a performance standpoint, I wouldn't recommend saving files as blobs in a database.

Comment: And @Nihilnovi from an experienced standpoint, I would not recommend to think of performance, unless your acceptance tests did not enforce you to do that. My hint is just because saving data to database is much cleaner and easier than writing it to hard disk. If that DB access is a bottleneck for you, provide caching with PHP or a proxy cache. Anyway the author is fine with your answer.

Comment: I wouldn't ever save files as blobs in a database unless you have some archaic system that forces you to do so. I highly recommend filesystem abstraction and edge computing for handling files, but that is beyond the scope and point of this question, a good starting point is a package made by the PHP League called Flysystem and the wikipedia page on ESI. 
https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes

Comment: I have used flysystem and ESIs. ESI is again an optimization (don't know why to mention it here?). I'll stop here. @Oleksandr Savchenko is maybe just writing a guestbook. He can decide on his own to have 2 or 3 lines in Doctrine or using your enterprise solution :).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't need big enterprice solution now. I prefer store files in filesystem and protect it by symfony controller. Thank you.